# FOLLOW UP anchor:1 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError Recaptcha

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, recaptcha

This is a follow up to my `Recaptcha call back can be found when it is the only function but not when other ones are included`.

Here is the link: [Recaptcha call back can be found when it is the only function but not when other ones are included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70776103/recaptcha-call-back-can-be-found-when-it-is-the-only-function-but-not-when-other)

Now I am not getting an error where ReCaptcha cannot find the callback function but instead I am getting this error: `anchor:1 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError`

Here is a picture:
[image]

When you click on `anchor:1`, it takes you to a page which I guess is where the ReCaptcha checkbox is hosted.

Here is a picture:
[image]

This was the URL `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=I_SUPPOSE_THIS_IS_SITE_KEY&hl=en&v=TDBxTlSsKAUm3tSIa0fwIqNu&size=normal&cb=52k0t5ji16jq`

That is how I know this has something to do with ReCaptcha...

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Jerry Bot Verication</title>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        

        <form action="?" method="post" class="recaptchaDIV">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="onloadCallback" data-sitekey="MY_SITE_KEY_WAS_HERE"></div>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function onloadCallback() {
                addPerson();
            }
        </script>

        <script type="module">

            window.addPerson = addPerson;

            const queryString = window.location.search;
            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
            const userVar = urlParams.get('user')

            userVarSplitted = userVar.split('#')
            userVarFormatted = userVarSplitted[0] + ":" + userVarSplitted[1]

            // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
            import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.4/firebase-app.js";
            import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.4/firebase-analytics.js";
            import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";
            // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
            // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

            // Your web app's Firebase configuration
            // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
            const firebaseConfig = {
                #firebase config
            };

            // Initialize Firebase
            const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
            const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
            const db = getDatabase();

            function addPerson() {
                set(ref(db, "verified/" + userVarFormatted), {
                    name: userVarSplitted[0],
                    discriminator: userVarSplitted[1]
                });

                console.log("added")
            }
        </script>

        <style>
            html, body{
                height: 100%;
            }
            body{
                display: flex;
                background: #fff;
                padding: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
            }
            .recaptchaDIV{
                margin: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

Do you know what's happened?

Thanks